# Setting button invisible with event not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, event-handling, user-controls, postback

I have a Visual Basic Project where I have a page(Parent.aspx) with a user control inside(ChildForm.ascx), the user control have a checkboxlist where if the selection is changed I cause a postback and send an event

```
Protected Sub checkBoxList_checked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles checkBoxList.SelectedIndexChanged
    RaiseEvent MyEvent(sender, e)
End Sub
```

to make a button invisible on the Parent view

```
    Protected Sub ChildForm_MyEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ChildForm.MyEvent

        If condition Then
            btnSave.Visible = False
        Else
            btnSave.Visible= True
        End If

End Sub
```

When I debug I see the breakpoint hitting all the lines of code and the condition apply as intended, but the button is not hidden, I dont know why if is setting the correct value it never refreshes the Parent page to show the changes, even if it does cause a postback.

Please help

Comment: @mxmissile No, the Event call is good, the Parent method can be called whatever as long as it has '`Handles ChildForm.MyEvent`

Comment: ahhh, I didnt scroll right enough :-)

Comment: Are your breakpoints hit *after* the page refreshes?

Comment: have you setted to "true"  this parameter "AutoPostBack"  ->  <asp:CheckBoxList  AutoPostBack="true"..................... ??

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj yes

Comment: Try to clear chache, remove bin folder also obj folder then retry! it must work with AutoPostBack to true

Answer (score 0):

Check your page load events (load, prerender, prerenderComplete) to make sure you are not setting the visibility property in there.  if you are, you may need to use
"If not IsPostBack"

Comment: There is no other place the visibility is changed